# Is there an easy way to directly compare voting records of two US Senators or Representatives?

Tags: united-states, congress, voting-records

I'm aware of sites like GovTrack and VoteSmart that let you examine any given Senator's or Representative's votes, but what I'd really like to do is get a side-by-side vote-by-vote comparison of the two Senators from my state. I want to zero in on the votes where they were on opposite sides.  Of course, I'd like this for the two Representatives from my state, too, or for the general case of any two members of the Senate or House.

I think an on-line tool for this would be incredibly useful, but I'd settle for a way to download their respective records so that I could pull them into a spreadsheet and line them up with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://usarep.org

You can compare votes of Senators and House Members apples to apples.

Currently, they are highlighting this for Presidential Primary candidates who are also Senators or Congress People.

What I like about this site is they have details of amendments voted on. While the Senate website gives a link to their amendments adjacent to the roll call, the ones for the House are harder to locate.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, there are plenty of data sources to look at someone's voting record, but not much for comparing two.

There is an (inactive) GitHub repo which alleges to do exactly what you want. The project is called [Compare-Congress](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/compare-congress) and it's by user sunlightlabs. Ordinarily I wouldn't recommend something like this, but I see that you are active on Stack Overflow, so maybe you can get some use out of it.

Answer (score 2):

On both the conservative and liberal sides of the ledger there are vote scoring organizations, like the Heritage Action Scorecard, that will allow you to do just that.

http://heritageactionscorecard.com/